# sorting search results in custom criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I will try to explain my problem as much as I can.

I have a search form where user can select different parameters and enter different values to perform a search for the properties. Like I have a table `tbl_properties`.

In search form user selects, `property_category`, `property_type` [a lease, sale or rent], inputs price range, `no_of_bedrooms`, `location`,`districts`, `property_area`, etc. The property attributes may be in `tbl_properties` or in other lookup tables. Writing query is not my problem, but the problem I m in is, I want to sort records in following pattern in search results

1. First show  result - price that matched the location in descending order
2. Then show - price that matched the district
3. Then show - No of bedrooms match in same district
4. Then show - Price/bedrooms/property area matched but in different district

I just want a hint how can the records be sorted in these orders?

**EDIT**

Here is the brief description of the table structure I have

```
tbl_properties
-------------------

property_id   INT
category_id    INT
property_name VARCHAR
price         INT
district_id   INT
location       VARCHAR
property_type  ENUM('lease','sale','rent')


tbl_category
-------------
category_id   INT
category_name VARCHAR


tbl_districts
-----------------
district_id INT
district_name VARCHAR


tbl_property_details
------------------------
detail_id      INT
property_id     INT
no_of_bedrooms  INT
property_area  DECIMAL
```

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you mean descending order for the price? as in, highest price first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
order by case
    when price between @priceMin and @priceMax 
        and location = @location then 1
    when price between @priceMin and @priceMax 
        and district_id = @districtid then 2
    when no_of_bedrooms = @no_of_bedrooms 
        and districtid = @districtid then 3
    when price between @priceMin and @priceMax 
        and no_of_bedrooms = @no_of_bedrooms 
        and property_area = @property_area and districtid <> @districtid then 4
    else 5
end, price desc
```

Answer (score -1):

select property_category property_type from tbl_properties where ***_*** __ _ _  ***_*** _  **ORDER BY**  ***_*__**;

so... ORDER BY price desc;

etc.

Here is a good link to use http://www.sqlcourse2.com/orderby.html

Comment: That is not what I wanted, please read my question carefully.